# How To Force Android ListView to change/update list item positions with less (scroll action/drag)?

Tags: java, android

I know my question might seem a little weird, but it goes as the following.
Usually for a given row in list view to go from lets say list position 1 to list position 2, it might require that view to be scrolled down a given number of pixels down, say 5px.

I'm not sure if this is the case for android but I get the impression that listview has some sort of variable that regulates the amount the list is dragged down to then define that our row is now  in position 2 instead of position 1.

If this is the case I would like to know if its possible to change this default amount to, lets say 2px. This way the amount of scrolling required for each row in the list to change position is less than what's set by default.

Comment: I doubt you have control over this with `ListView`. There is far greater chance that you can do something like this with `RecyclerView`, particularly with a custom layout manager.